# How to make wpf row shrink to fit contents

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a grid with two rows plus a grid splitter.  I want the top row's height to be as small as possible by default (in this case, the height of the button) The bottom row should expand to take up the remaining space in the grid.  I want the grid splitter there to allow the user to change the size as needed.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="A little old button" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

How should I setup the xaml?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

should do it.

Comment: Is there any other consideration to be take into account. In my case, stuff actually get more spread using *Auto*. I've tried to play around with *MinHeight* and *MaxHeight* but didn't really got it right. I have a grid with stack panels in it and each stack panel has a label and a combo box. (Yes, I've been trying out styles for each of them, including the row definitions.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten have you tried `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` for the rows that have to be automatically expanded.